# Getting AH02032 using TLSv1.2 despite identical SNI server name and Hostname, but SNI has the port number attached. No error in test env. with TLSv1.3

Tags: ssl, openssl, sni

Getting the the error message below despite identical Hostnames. What I don't understand, why the Hostname provided via SNI has the port number attached even though, according to Hostname specification, the colon and port number is not listed as part of the Hostname definition and the OpenSSL SNI extension treats the server name as Hostname. Is this a parsing error in Apache (and Wireshark)?

A tcp dump from a Debian client viewed with Wireshark lists during client hello and TLSv1.2 under SNI extension:

*Server Name Type: Host_Name (0)* and
*Server Name: MyHostname:443*

While the client would allow TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2 seems to be mandated by the server during Client Hello.

The request is made using OpenSSL 3.07 cmp

Error Message:
*AH02032: Hostname MyHostname:443 provided via SNI and Hostname MyHostname provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup uri="path"*

I would expect that when the package is parsed by Apache/SNI, the server name is taken without port and compared with the host name in the http header and be recognized as identical.

In a similar, but not identical to production environment, when TLSv1.3 is used, the error is not occurring with otherwise identical client settings.

(I don't have access to the Apache server which is part of a web application firewall.)

Amendment:

cmd:
bin/openssl cmp -config etc/openssl.cnf -cmd ir -section cmp-init -ref [ref] -secret pass:[pass]-certout ssl/PKIstore/[store.pem] -newkey ssl/PKIstore/[new.key] -subject [SUBJECT DN] -implicit_confirm

openssl.cnf
[default]
[cmp]
[cmp-init]
prompt = no
recipient = [ca-dn]
path = [path]
tls_host = MyHostname
tls_used = yes
server = MyHostname:443
path = [default path]
trusted = [trusted.pem]
cacertsout = [capubs.pem]

Note: The values for server, tls_host, and tls_used are defined in a opensssl.cfg file.

After further investigating the packet:

Whatever is given as *server = [value]*
value ends up as Server Name in the server_name extension. And the length value includes the length of prefix *https://* prefix or the port *:443* if given as server value.  *[prefix][server_value][:port]*

If either prefix or suffix are used, the server name does not matches the server name in the host header. If only server is given, the request is send to the default port 80, even if tls_used is set to yes.

Since the SNI server Name Type is host_name, I would expect, that it should not contains the protocol prefix nor the port.

Comment: *"What I don't understand, why the Hostname provided via SNI has the port number attached even though"* - the request is done by the client. Likely the client is broken or used in a  broken way. Not enough is known about the client though to help. *"The request is made using OpenSSL 3.07 cmp"* - this is not sufficient information. Please provide the exact command line you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Added command and configfile as requested, plus further insights.

Comment: *"I would expect that when the package is parsed by Apache/SNI, the server name is taken without port and compared with the host name in the http header and be recognized as identical."* - No, the server_name field is not supposed to contain the port in the first place. It is also not supposed to be used for IP addresses, only for hostnames.

Comment: *"server = MyHostname:443"* - why don't you simply use `https://MyHostname` as server, i.e. without port?

Comment: https:// MyHostname results in SNI Server Name https://MyHostname as explained above. Omitting https:// and :443 results in openssl cmp sending the request to MyHostname:80 even when tls_use = yes.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in OpenSSL to me and I've filed it as such: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20031

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Thanks for confirming it  and for the bug report!